# How to return a column max substring with full column values?

Tags: sql

Everyone. I am facing a problem. I have a query like following:

```
SELECT  MAX(SUBSTRING(account_code ,5,3 )) as first_level_code 
FROM acc_coa 
WHERE category = '1';
```

Which work fine but now I need to get with full column values. I am attempting this way but not work.

```
SELECT  account_code, MAX(SUBSTRING(account_code ,5,3 )) as first_level_code 
FROM acc_coa 
WHERE category = '1'
```

How can i achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: All RDBMS(MySQL, SQL Server, Postgresql)?

Answer (score 2):

use subselect

```
SELECT  account_code, SUBSTRING(account_code ,5,3 ) as first_level_code 
  from FROM acc_coa  
  where SUBSTRING(account_code ,5,3 ) = (SELECT MAX(SUBSTRING(account_code ,5,3 )) as first_level_code 
 FROM acc_coa 
 WHERE category = '1') ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `group by account_code` at end of query

Comment: here account_code column is unique

Comment: Still account_code needs to be in a group by clause because you are using an aggregate function

Answer (score 1):

Use `ORDER BY` and a way of getting one row:

```
SELECT  c.*, SUBSTRING(account_code, 5, 3) as first_level_code
FROM acc_coa c
WHERE category = '1'
ORDER BY SUBSTRING(account_code, 5, 3) DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

Note:  `FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY` is the ANSI-standard mechanism for getting one row.  Some databases use `LIMIT` or `TOP` or other mechanisms.